# assembleTask is null in android gradle plugin 2.2-alpha2 for spoon plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-run

In the zipalign task creation method from gradle plugin

```
        InstantRunBuildContext instantRunBuildContext = this.getScope().getVariantScope().getInstantRunBuildContext();
        this.zipAlignTask = this.taskManager.createZipAlignTask(taskName, instantRunBuildContext, inputFile, outputFile);
        this.assembleTask.dependsOn(new Object[]{this.zipAlignTask});
        return this.zipAlignTask;
```

Now, assembleTask is null and in turn will throw

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: A dependency must not be empty
```

I have checked earlier version, assembleTask has the actual assemble task

Comment: downvote because of what?

Comment: which os r u using ?

Comment: os x, latest android studio 2.2 preview 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has been fixed in the latest android gradle plugin
see here [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210444)

Answer (score 0):

Try This
go to

File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Comment: as I said , all the options are disabled

Answer (score 0):

apparently this is an issue in the plugin itself, will wait for the stable build, as seen here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210444